# How to prove there is no moment generating function for t distribution

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, t-distribution, moment-generating-function

I'm struggling to show that the [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Definition) for [t distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) does not exist.

So far I tried to show the moment generating function diverges from its integration but the computation is not so easy (I'm stuck at partial integration). If there is any easier way to show that there is no MGF without any computation or any hints for the further computation, it would be great.

Comment: If it existed, its MacLaurin series coefficients would be proportional to its moments.  What is the sequence of moments of any $t$ distribution?  You don't need to know them all--just compute moments $k$ or $k+1$ of the distribution (whichever is even) with $k$ degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the moment generating function $M_X(t) = \mathbb{E} e^{t X}$ of the random variable $X$ exists (for $t$ in some open interval containing zero), then *all* the moments of $X$ exists. So one way to show that $t$ distributions do not have moment generating functions is to show that not all moments exist.

But [it is well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Moments) that the $t$-distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom only have moments up to order $\nu-1$, so the mgf do not exist.